# “read” works as expected in ZSH but behaves differently when using any other shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh

I’ve written a short `while`-`do` cycle but I found it working strange with different shells.

That's it:

```
find "`pwd`" -type d | while read -r D; do ls ${D}; done
```

When I start it using `zsh`, all goes nice. However, using any other shell it breaks when I launch it in any directory with escaped character in title.

Why is that so? I tried to play with `read -d`, but it ignores any kind of escaped characters like \n. `read -r` also doesn't anything.

Comment: Can you try a different version of it? `find * -type d -print0 | xargs -0 ls`?

Comment: Try changing `${D}` to `"$D"`.  Then, if that works, forget about it and use `find … -print0 | xargs -0 …` or `find … -type d -exec ls {} ";"`.  But don't use `find *`, use `find .`, unless you really need to use the full pathname for some reason; in that case, use `find "$PWD"`, `find "$(pwd)"`, or `find "\`pwd\`"`.

Comment: In a nutshell, word splitting. zsh does not do word splitting unless configured to. Quote your variables! aka "${D}".

Comment: @fd0, thx, quotes solved everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
`find "$(pwd)" -type d | while read -r D; do ls -lb "${D}"; done`

With just a bare `ls` all you will see in bash is a `?` for a filename that is equal to e.g. "\n".
Also `-print0 | xarg -0` may well be necessary in these cases, and an unquoted `$D` when $D contains whitespace is likely to be the cause for trouble.

`$ man ls` excerpt:

```
-b, --escape
      print C-style escapes for nongraphic characters
-l    use a long listing format
```

---

**The unwise stuff:**
Example: `$ rm "$(echo -en "\r")"` - allows removal of a file with a single carriage return (CR) as name.

And of course if you want to fiddle with this:
`$ echo "TEST" >"This is a filename with a CR _$(echo -en "\r")_here"`
... creates a file.

`$ rm "This is a filename with a CR _$(echo -en "\r")_here"`
... to remove it.

Comment: Thx, quotes helped me. However, in real cycle I used I needed to execute mv with {} used twice, so xargs was not useful.

Comment: Typically, one would use `$'\r'` instead of `$(echo -en "\r")`.

Comment: Interesting, haven't seen that before, do you have a reference? Is this bash/zsh only?  Note that `echo` is 'built in' for bash, the difference might not be that notable there.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is that so?

`${D}` is the same as `$D`. It will be replaced by the shell by the content of the variable `D`. So if `D` contains `Hello World`, your

```
ls -lb $D
```

becomes

```
ls -lb Hello World
```

which will try to list the 2 directories `Hello` and `World` (instead of the 1 directory `Hello World`).

[Scott](https://superuser.com/users/150988/scott) already gave you the correct way: use `"$D"`, which will result in

```
ls -lb "Hello World"
```